# How to get the event of the partialview button in a jQuery modal dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a partial view named xyz and I have a lot of buttons on it which implements different functionality.

```
 $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 700,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) { $(this).load('<%=Url.Action("PushButton","Body",new {Parm="text",Parm1="Value"}) %>'); },
        position: 'top' 
    });
```

I'm opening this partial view XYZ in a jQuery modal dialog box. I have some buttons in the partialview XYZ. I'm not getting how to fire the event explicitly. Like if I want to close the dialog box by click of the button created in Partialview.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wire the button events once the load is complete.  You can add a callback to the load to notify you: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: can u provide me any demo for it which uses button event

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I want my partial view to be independent and submit using Ajax. It's similar to creating a user control.

I am now planning to use a publisher/subscriber mechanism to listen to an event from my partial view. The parent can listen to this event and close the dialog box.

I came across [Ben Alman's Pub/Sub gist](https://gist.github.com/661855).

Another good article for the observer pattern in JavaScript is *[Learning JavaScript Design Patterns, The Observer Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript)*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the callback on the load event:

```
 $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 700,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
     open: function (event, ui) { $(this).load('<%=Url.Action("PushButton","Body",new {Parm="text",Parm1="Value"}) %>', function(){
         $("#buttonId").click(function(){
             //Stuff you want to do with the button here
         });
     }); },
        position: 'top' 
    });
```

You can do this inside document.ready as well:

```
$(document).on('click', '#idOfControlInsideDialog', function() {
      //Stuff you want to do here
});
```